# Can the Added as Colleague email text/format be changed?

Tags: email-templates

A 'C' level person really doesn't like the email he gets when someone adds him as a colleague.
Can this be changed?

I've tracked it down to a AddToColleaguesButton control in MyContactLinks.aspx but don't know how to track it further.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is NO **supported** way of modifying text/format of email that goes out when a colleague is added. The text/format is hard coded in a private method (Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ColleagueManager class) in an assembly that ships with SharePoint.

The list of email templates which you can customize is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802738.aspx And that does not include the email template in question.

Also check a similar problem here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/4b6ffbc5-3942-450e-b11b-9754551873aa/